# Sed removes lines, but leaves white space?

Tags: shell, script, sed

Having trouble with this code. It removes lines matching the date (in my case, 09/05/17) which is fine. But in its place there are just blank lines.

Anyone got a solution?

```
sed -i -e "s|$PrevDay.*$||" $DataFile2
```

Comment: If anyone is interested in trying this, the full script in which this code is implemented is available here: https://pastebin.com/9AuQDjtc

Comment: You should post a sample of the input file so we can test the solutions against it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822809/delete-lines-with-sed-match-a-special-regex) similar question, then try `sed -i -e "/$PrevDay.*$/d" $DataFile2`. Or use `awk -i '!/$PrevDay.*$/ {print $0}' $DataFile2`.

Comment: If you want to maintain the pipe `|` separator, use `sed -i -e "\|$PrevDay.*$|d" $DataFile2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding my previous comment into an answer.

```
sed -i -e "\|$PrevDay.*$|d" $DataFile2
```

**Explanation:** You are using a function that substitutes text in each line. You chose the `|` character as the delimiter, wrote the expression to be removed between the first and the second delimiter and the expression to be inserted between the second and the third delimiter. Thus, the line is edited but not deleted.

If you want to delete the line, you should use a different syntax:

`\|` defines `|` as the delimiter instead of the default `/`

`$PrevDay.*$` is the pattern to be searched, where `$PrevDay` is a variable from you bash script

`|` marks the end of the search pattern

`d` means that the line matching the pattern is to be deleted

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822809/delete-lines-with-sed-match-a-special-regex) similar question on Stackoverflow.

As is common in the UNIX-like wolrd, the same outcome can be accomplished in a different way, e.g. using `awk`; the following expression means: "if the patterns is not matched, print the whole line".

```
awk -i '!/$PrevDay.*$/ {print $0}' $DataFile2
```

Comment: I did look for the command for awk to do it. It ended up printing out everything except the lines that had $PrevDay in them. Didn't work when it came to putting it into a file though, so I looked to use sed. Thanks for the explanation too, learning to script bash is pretty fun.

Answer (score -1):

Give it a try: `sed -i -e "s|$PrevDay.*$||" $DataFile2 | grep -v '^$'`

If your input line is not empty but contains white space characters, you can use

```
sed -i -e "s|$PrevDay.*$||" $DataFile2 | grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*$'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to remove the invisible lines still unfortunately.

Comment: @Interknet See edit.